# Debian netinstall over Wi-Fi?

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, system-installation

I have a question about installing Debian. Ubuntu has this option which can install all missing packages from Ethernet or Wi-Fi, while Debian has only the Ethernet option. The firmware I prepare -> [see tutorial](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch06s04) and it's working.

But if I do netinstall, Debian will not ask for a Wi-Fi key or password. 
Ubuntu, on the other hand, will ask and install elements over Wi-Fi.

Is it possible to prepare a Debian ISO image such that the Debian installer will install missing elements over Wi-Fi?

Answer (score 2):

By default, non-free firmware isn't present in the Debian installer and in many cases this will result in the WLAN adapter not being detected during the installation. This is probably why you didn't get the option to connect to a Wi-Fi network during installation.

However, there are unofficial installer images available that *do* include non-free firmware. By using one of these, the installer will ask you to specify your SSID and password and offer you more options to download packages during installation. From [the Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware#Firmware_during_the_installation):

> Alternatively, you can use one of the parallel installer image builds that also include all the non-free firmware packages directly. We have "netinst" CD images and also DVD installer images - see http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/

This link isn't promoted much in the official documentation but it can come in quite handy when installing Debian on laptops!